# In openSUSE setup cannot pass the suggested partitioning

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

I'm tryna setup openSUSE as virtual but in the 'Suggested Partitioning' part, it gives error when I pressed to next button.

I have tried to shrinking my disk and also checked the VMD in BIOS(it's enabled).(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kY1j.png)